# What does とろミノ mean / what is it?

Tags: translation, meaning, food

I was watching Samurai Gourmet on netflix today, and in the following scene i tried to read the menu on the left side of the screen:

[image]

I marked the item that is interesting me with a red box. If it am not mistaken it reads "Toromino". I was trying to find a meaning via google, but i am completely lost on that one. Any idea what dish that refers to?

Comment: Just look up トロ and ミノ separately and combine the meanings.

Comment: [「とろミノ」って「ミノサンド」のこと](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E3%83%9F%E3%83%8E%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%22&oq=%22%E3%83%9F%E3%83%8E%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59.10657j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22%E3%83%9F%E3%83%8E%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%22+%22%E3%81%A8%E3%82%8D%E3%83%9F%E3%83%8E%22)なんだって～。（でもミノサンドって何？）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

とろミノ is made of two words:

- [とろ](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A8%E3%82%8D) usually means *fatty*, but it may mean something like *melty* or *soft* here.
- [ミノ](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%83%9F%E3%83%8E) refers to *the first stomach* of a cow ([cows are said to have four stomachs](https://www.quora.com/How-many-stomachs-does-a-cow-have-and-what-does-each-one-do).) Also known as *rumen*.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like ミノ is an intestine called [rumen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumen), used for 'fermentation of ingested feed.' とろ implies a fattiness.

Answer (score 0):

ミノ is called tripe in [UK] English. It requires long cooking (two hours plus) to become soft enough to be palatable, so I think this is probably "cooked tripe".